# Scope of expression in a user-defined function

Tags: functions, replacement, scoping

I have the following code:

```
fbasic = A + R + Z*Z *Z*Z;
f[A_, Z_, R_] := fbasic + R;
f[0, 2, 3]
```

The answer I am getting is

> ```
> 3 + A + R + Z^4
> ```

Which is not what I want because the `fbasic` is not replaced by the expression. How can I do that?

Comment: Try using `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. Could you give me more information about the difference between := and =? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: By the way, if I use Set rather than SetDelayed, how can I call this function later? Because "fbasic"can be an arbitrary function.

Comment: @user8551 http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users#answer-18487

Answer (score 2):

For example, use `Set Delayed` and arguments

```
fbasic[a_, z_, r_] := a + r + z^4;
f[a_, z_, r_] := fbasic[a, z, r] + r;
f[0, 2, 3]
```

Another option is:

```
fbasic = aa + rr + zz^4;
f[a_, z_, r_] := Evaluate[fbasic /. {rr -> r, aa -> a, zz -> z}] + r;
f[0, 2, 3]
```

Or:

```
fbasic = aa + rr + zz^4;
f[a_, z_, r_] := Block[{rr = r, aa = a, zz = z}, fbasic + r]
f[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. But in my code, there is a loop. Sometimes I don't the expression of "fbasic" which is calculated by the previous one. How I define this kind of function?

Comment: @user8551 That seems another kind of question. Could you edit your question specifying the problem a little bit more?

Comment: Omit `Evaluate`?

Comment: The concept of my code is: I write a function to calculate the multidimensional numerical integration.The input is a function. The output is the value which is the numerical integration. The first part of the code is 'FNintegration[fbasic_] := f[A_, Z_, R_] := fbasic;.....' . fbasic is an arbitrary function of A,Z and R.I need to get the value with different A Z and R. That is why I define another function f[A_, Z_, R_]. I want to call this function later. Thanks for your kind help.